# Extending HMENU with extensions records

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In my extension there are categories and products. I want the categories to be shown as submenu.

My page tree looks like this:

- Home
- Clothes (uid: 2)
- Special Offers (uid: 3)

  - Workwear (uid: 4)

On pages "Clothes" (uid: 2) and "Workwear" (uid: 4) I have a plugin that will show the categories and products.

The categories to be shown are defined in TS setup (with an ext+ template on each pages) like this:

```
plugin.tx_productsdb.settings.categories = 1,2,3,4
```

the typoscript for my subnavigation looks like this:

```
nav.subnavigation = COA
nav.subnavigation {

  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    entryLevel = 0

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      wrap = <ul>|</ul>
      NO = 0
      NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>

      ACT = 1
      ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active first">|</li> |*| <li class="active">|</li> |*| <li class="active last">|</li>
      ACT.ATagParams = class="active"

      CUR < .ACT
    }
    2 < .1
    2.wrap = <ul class="level2">|</ul>
    3 < .1
    3.wrap = <ul class="level3">|</ul>
  }
}
```

I already tried to use the **itemArrayProcFunc** property of HMENU, but I couldn't find an example on how to use it with my namespaced extension.

i tried this:

```
  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    entryLevel = 0
    itemArrayProcFunc = Vendor\Extension\Hooks\Subnavigation->process
```

And here's the function:

```
class Subnavigation
{
    /**
     * @param $menuArr
     * @param $conf
     */
    public function process(&$menuArr, &$conf)
    {
        // show me, that something is happening here ... pretty please!
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($menuArr);
        exit;
    }
}
```

If you've got any example on how to do it, please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a project with products and categories.
The categories should be displayed in the menu and I solved it by JavaScript which is calling an AJAX method.
The AJAX method calls a predefined page type e.g. `index.php?id=xx&type=xx`

The TypoScript looks like this:

```
menuItems = PAGE
menuItems.typeNum = xx
menuItems {
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        no_cache = 1
    }
    10 = USER_INT
    10.userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    10 {
        extensionName = ExtensionName
        pluginName = Plugin
        vendorName = Vendor
        controller = Product
        action = getMenu
        switchableControllerActions {
            Product {
                1 = getMenu
            }
        }
        view < plugin.tx_plugin.view
        persistence < plugin.tx_plugin.persistence
        settings < plugin.tx_plugin.settings
    }
}
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function getMenuAction()
{
    $menuItems = [];
    $categories = $this->categoryRepository->findAll();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        /** @var Category $category */
        $menuItems[] = [
            'name' => $category->getTitle(),
            'link' => $this->getLinkForCategory($category),
            'id' => $category->getUid()
        ];
    }

    $this->view->assign('menuItems', $menuItems);
    echo $this->view->render();
    exit;
}
```

In Fluid you only have to create the

structure for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, after many failed attempts, **I discarded** my approach with **itemArrayProcFunc**.

My solution has some similarities to the one Thomas posted.

I'm using a TS condition and build the navigation completely on my own.

```
[PIDinRootline = 2] || [PIDinRootline = 3]
lib.subnav >
lib.subnav = USER_INT
lib.subnav {
  userFunc       = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  vendorName     = Vendor
  extensionName  = ExtensionName
  pluginName     = pluginName
  controller     = Controller
  action         = getSubnavigation

  view < plugin.tx_plugin.view
  persistence < plugin.tx_plugin.persistence
  settings < plugin.tx_plugin.settings
}
[global]
```

And my controller action:

```
public function getSubnavigationAction()
{

    $rootline = $this->pageRepository->getRootLine($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id);

    // assumption: main page is always on level 1
    $rootId = $rootline[1]['uid'];
    $treePids = $this->getTreePids($rootId);
    $pages = $this->pageRepository->getMenuForPages($treePids, 'uid, pid, title', 'sorting', ' AND hidden=0 AND deleted=0');
    $rootPage = $pages[$rootId];

    $tree = $this->buildTree($rootPage, $pages);
    $menu = $this->buildMenu($tree);

    $current = $this->argumentService->getArgument('tx_productsdb_categories', 'category');
    $parent = 0;
    if($this->argumentService->hasArgument('tx_productsdb_categories', 'parent')) {
        $parent = $this->argumentService->getArgument('tx_productsdb_categories', 'parent');
    }

    $this->view->assign('parent', $parent);
    $this->view->assign('current', $current);
    $this->view->assign('menu', $menu);
    $this->view->assign('settings', $this->settings);
}
```

The menu is then build in Fluid.